# How to output to the last line of a file from a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm working on a batch file for my program's setup.

I want to make a log from the batch file that logs the run time and date I created:

```
     (
     echo Setup Run Log
     echo The setup was runned at %time% on %date% by %username%.
     )>run.log.
```

But every time the code runs it over writes the information in the file. 
I want that the first time the batch starts a run.log file to be created that has Setup Run Log and every other time the batch runs the time, date and username be written on the line below a line that already has something written.

My question: How to output to the last line in a file.

Comment: Could you please clarify what operating system and what batch file system you are using? Do you mean the batch system in some version of Windows?

Comment: To append to a file double the redirection symbol `>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing (command) > run.log, change your code to (command) >> run.log.

">" redirects and overwrites. ">>" appends the content.

More details about command redirection is at https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html.

Comment: Thank you, all this time I'm creating batch files I didn't know the difference between > and >>.

Comment: As it happens, your answer is correct.   But your reference is dead wrong; the question is about a CMD batch file on Windows.   (Even for Unix / Linux / Bash, though, TLDP is not a great reference.)